# Can't access controller from element

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am trying to use content filled from a controller inside an element so I can use the content to build a view.

So far I have the following element (.ctp file)

```
<?php $categories = $this->requestAction('categories/menu'); ?>

<ul class="hidden">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $categorie): ?>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link($categorie->name, '#'); ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

with this controller

```
class CategoriesController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = $this->Categories->find('all');
        $this->set(compact('categories'));
    }

    public function menu()
    {
        $categories = $this->paginate();
        $this->set('categories', $categories);
    }
}
```

When using the code from here I got an error in the log and nothing display on the page `Error: [Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException] Template file "Categories\menu.ctp" is missing.`
.

If I change this ligne `$this->set('categories', $categories);`for this one `return $categories;` I have the following error displaying on my page `Error: Controller action can only return an instance of Response`.

I originally tryed the code from [this tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html) (sorry for the scrolling just go to the last example before *Caching Elements*) but it lead to the second error message.

How can I use a `Controller` from an `Element`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, a controller needs a view template to render unless you explicitly disabled/circumvent view rendering by either setting `Controller::$autoRender` to `false`, by making the method return a `Response` object, or by using [**serialized data views**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key).

The latter is what the error message tells you the method is expected to return, see **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#controller-actions**

> When you use controller methods with `Routing\RequestActionTrait::requestAction()` you will typcially return a `Response` instance. If you have controller methods that are used for normal web requests + requestAction, you should check the request type before returning
>
> ```php
> // src/Controller/RecipesController.php
>
> class RecipesController extends AppController
> {
>     public function popular()
>     {
>        $popular = $this->Recipes->find('popular');
>         if (!$this->request->is('requested')) {
>             $this->response->body(json_encode($popular));
>             return $this->response;
>         }
>         $this->set('popular', $popular);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> [...]

### View cells

As it looks like you just want to fetch and render model data, I'd suggest to check out view cells.

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html**

Comment: thank you. I will have a look at this tonight and I will comeback to give you feed back

Comment: Cell where exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very mutch you save me many hour of headache

Answer (score 0):

What you should have is the following:

```
public function menu()
{
    $categories = $this->Categories->find('all');
    if($this->request->is('requested'):
        $this->response->body($categories);
    endif;
}
```